# Getting error AWS lambda function timeout with step functions

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-step-functions

I'm getting timeout error because need to migrate a dynamodb table to the new one. There are many items in old table.So, i'm using lastevaluatedkey for pagination to read operations, but lambda functions live 15 minutes. So, I create a step function as below:

```
{
  "Comment": "DynamoDB Scan Workflow",
  "StartAt": "ScanDynamoDB",
  "States": {
    "ScanDynamoDB": {
      "Type": "Task",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:**********:function:dynamo-table-migrator",
      "Next": "IsScanComplete"
    },
    "IsScanComplete": {
      "Type": "Choice",
      "Choices": [
        {
          "Variable": "$.LastEvaluatedKey",
          "IsPresent": true,
          "Next": "ScanDynamoDB"
        }
      ],
      "Default": "Done"
    },
    "Done": {
      "Type": "Succeed"
    }
  }
}
```

My lambda function's timeout is 10 minutes. I increased it from 30 seconds and it actually migrate almost half of the table but then again gives error. The error:

```
The cause could not be determined because Lambda did not return an error type. Returned payload: {"errorMessage":"2024-01-10T06:55:49.427Z 4730971c-c428-4692-aa23-4486932da4f2 Task timed out after 600.18 seconds"}
```

Comment: Since the old table is large and that the lambda has a max runtime limit of 15 min (non-negotiable) it will eventually time out without completing.  If this is a one time process of doing the copy. Why not try using aws cli. If you need to this as a part of the workflow. I would recommend something that lives longer like  Glue.

Comment: Because I'm a little manipulating data. Type casting or rename the attribute name in new table, thats why I need to use code for this. Okay but Idk what is the reason of time out ?  Lambda still have may be 5 minutes for live but it is timeout after 10 minutes. Also I'm doing that:
                 if context.get_remaining_time_in_millis() < 30000: 
                       return {"LastEvaluatedKey": response['LastEvaluatedKey']}

Comment: when you say "My lambda function's timeout is 10 minutes." it means you are specifically asking your lambda to timeout after 10 min which is why its timing out around 600.13 = ~10 min. try setting the timeout to be max thats 15 min . you might get lucky and the process will finish by then else the surest option will be to use something like AWS Backup / AWS Glue.

Comment: Thank you so much. I will check Glue, or Jobs may be I will try.

Comment: You can do simple manipulation like type casting and renaming attributes in aws glue as well.

Answer (score 1):

I hope this is one time process to migrate table: I mean not usual task for you.

Just check once if you can improve process:

- are you reading and writing data from both tables in the same lambda call.
- **Just check if you can already read and prepare data.**

**Quick Way:**

- you can export data to file.
- prepare new data using your code.
- upload new data file to S3, as Dynamo likes it for import data
- [directly load data in Dynamo DB from this S3 file](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/S3DataImport.HowItWorks.html)

**Other Way:**

- you can export data to file.
- prepare new data using your code and store it in Dynamo as you are doing already.
- Just don't read and write at once.

Comment: No it will migrate only 1 table. Yes I thought exporting data, but there are 56 million item only 1 table. And for exporting whole data, I need to go end of the table. That's why I need to scan it with pagination in code. Yes I'm reading and updating old table, writing to new table, in the same lambda call. But I'm marking items as migrated in the old table thats how I'm sure that there is no duplicate items

Comment: Then why don't you use small ec2 machine to execute this task. I don't see any benefit/limitation of using lambda here. - 
Can you explain why did you choose lambda, it will cost you lot more than a simple ec2 machine, you can also use a very small like t2.

Comment: Yes, I will use k8s Jobs for this task. I thought it will be 1 time work that's why I chose lambda, but you are right. It is not enough such a this task. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I do not have enough reputation to comment.

What is the allocated memory for the lambda function?
You could potentially increase it if the load is too heavy. Naturally, this has its limit though and comes at a higher cost.

See also the documentation [Lambda Memory Optimization](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-function-common.html#configuration-memory-optimization-accept).